# monitoring spark cluster in AWS EMR without spark UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, emr, apache-spark-2.0

I am running a spark cluster on AWS EMR. How do I get all all the details of the jobs and executors that are running on AWS EMR without using the spark UI. I am going to use it for monitoring and optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout nagios or ganglia for cluster health but you cant see the jobs running on spark with these tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS EMR you can do that using lynx server. something like below.

1. Login to the master node of the cluster.
2. try the below command

   lynx http://localhost:4040

Note : before you type the command make sure you are running a job